# How can I cause the compiler to issue an error for classes that define the method body when using the __interface keyword?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, interface, abstract-class

After reading this article: [Using Interfaces in C++](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/CppInterfaces.aspx)

I have decided to use the `__interface` keyword with a macro that will add virtual destructors as described in the above link.

I was happy that the `__interface` keyword will cause the compiler to enforce interface rules, but I was disappointed when I took it for a test drive... It turns out that the `__interface` keyword does not enforce the rule that a method in the interface should not contain a method body.

I can of course add a macro for function methods but I don't want to do this. Does anyone have any other suggestions?

**EDIT**: portability is a none issue for me because i must compile on both windows and linux so i will use the `__interface` keyword when i'm on windows and not on linux , that will be in order to enforce the below rules , **which can't be enforced via abstract base class**:

1. Can inherit from zero or more base interfaces.
2. Can only contain public, pure virtual methods.
3. Cannot contain data members; properties are allowed.
4. Cannot inherit from a base class.
5. Cannot contain constructors, destructors, or operators.
6. Cannot contain static methods.

besides the destructor issue which can be workaround one can see the advantage of using this keyword in windows env of course.

Comment: I agree with most commenters to that article you link to: this is simply macro abuse. If you are serious about enforcing restrictions on your interface classes, do that with a tool that parses the code (shouldn't be that hard, you only need to parse a small subset of the grammar and only well enough to check a few conditions). Otherwise, don't bother because you are simply trading one set of "programmer discipline" rules for another. I see no benefit in that.

Comment: +1 Jon for your opinion, i will consider it, though i don't want  to be depended on external tool to enforce interface restrictions.

Comment: C++ doesn't have tools to enforce a specific programming style. It allows you to do things the way you want, and it allows you to mix and match different styles. Some languages only support their "one true style", and doesn't have this "problem" that you can choose. If you don't want function bodies, just don't add them!

Comment: @_Avishay_: It appears the only answer you will accept is "wow, that's a great idea!" The comments and answers say something very different. You should take that as a sign that this just might not be such a good idea after all.

Comment: @_Avishay_: The two statements `Portability is a none issue` & ` i must compile on both windows and linux` grossly contradict each other. Also, How are you planning to implement this on Linux? I hope you understand Linux is not Windows to begin with.

Comment: @_Avishay_: Really! Atleast try understanding what is being asked, How will you enforce the same interface rules on Linux? I assume you understand `__interface` wont be available on Linux since it is Microsoft compiler extension.

Comment: @Als: if you will read my post you will see that i said i must compile on both Windows and linux , meaning : windows will give errors when interface rules will not be obyed, was it hard for you to understand that ? , if so i can further explain it...

Comment: @_Avishay_: Bother not, be happy if you understand it, We don't :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__interface` is a microsoft **specific extension**. It's not standard and not portable.

Also, C++ allows for pure `virtual` method to have function body.

```
class Base {
  virtual void foo () = 0;
};
void Base::foo ()
{ } // ok
```

It's advisable to **explicitly** declare `virtual` destructor in the class body.

Comment: the question is not wether its portable ... i understand its microsoft specific....

Comment: +1 for "C++ allows for pure virtual method to have function body"

Comment: "C++ allows for pure virtual method to have function body". This probably explains why MSVC doesn't check for it when you're using the `__interface` extension. One thing to note is that the  `__interface` extension doesn't allow you to declare a virtual destructor in the class body. (See the article linked in the question.)

Answer (score 6):

There is no interface keyword in ***Standard C++*** as in Java, What you have in C++ are Abstract Base Classes.

An Abstract Base Class is a class which has atleast one pure virtual function and an object of such a class cannot be created but a pointer or reference to it can be created. Thus it can be used to simulate the behavior of interfaces.

***Example of Abstract class as an interface***

```
class Shape
{
    public:
        virtual void draw()=0;
};

class Rectangle:public Shape
{

    public:
       void draw()
       {
           //draw a Rectangle
       }    
};


int main()
{
    Shape *ptr = new Rectangle();
    ptr->draw();  //calls draw() of Rectangle class

    return 0;
}
```

***Note that:***

`__interface` keyword as a new ***Microsoft extension to the C++ compiler.***
That is non C++ Standard specified and Non portable.

EDIT: This answer was to a question titled "***`__interface` keyword Win c++***" and was tagged `C++`.

Comment: @_Avishay_: Do you understand what a Compiler Extension means? and the difference between C++ Standard and Compiler Extensions?

Comment: @_Avishay_, @Als answer is correct. It's pointed out in standard C++ context.

Comment: @_Avishay_ just because you can #define or typedef something (or if you create the compiler, make reserved keywords), doesn't mean it exists in the language. +1 @Als

Comment: @_Avishay_: Can you please summarize what exactly he should have understood from that article?

Comment: **There is no such thing as "WIN C++".** As Als explains, this is a compiler extension provided by Microsoft's C/C++ compiler. It has nothing to do with Windows, and it's definitely *not* part of C++.

Comment: That said, I imagine the reason this answer was downvoted is because it doesn't actually answer the question. You simply seem to assume that non-standard, non-portable extensions are inherently evil, and must avoided at all costs. That's not necessarily true; they're obviously implemented and provided for a reason. You don't explain how to achieve what the asker wants to achieve. If your position is that it's not possible (or that he should use an abstract base class to do so), you ought to consider making that more explicit in your answer.

Comment: @Cody Gray: Was formulating an code sample. Does that qualify as an answer?

Comment: Indeed it does. I agree with this solution, btw, so there's your +1. :-) Compiler-specific extensions are sometimes useful, but I can't see how there's an advantage here of `__interface` over an abstract base class.

Comment: I downvoted because the question was obviously about Visual C++ (even before I went and tagged it that way), the questions was about "Why doesn't the compiler enforce things it says it's supposed to enforce?" and your answer doesn't answer that.

Comment: @Ken Bloom: Well, the answer explained why it is a bad idea and an alternative staying within the boundaries of Standard C++. The commentators & the voting pattern on the answer do agree my understanding that is qualify's as answer, obviously you don't so you should probably come up with an answer which answers what you think is the Q.

Comment: @Als: I don't use Visual C++ (or Windows), so I don't have an answer, but I certainly disagree with the "Standard C++ elitism" that triggers a knee jerk "That's not standard C++" answer, when someone asks a specific questions about a specific compilers on StackOverflow. And @Cody Gray: I'm also not inclined to be pedantic about how people refer to compilers unless it's unclear about which compiler they meant.